# css stylesheet not getting added

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I load any web page. Then open firebug console and run the below javascript, which creates a link element in the head of the page. the code is below.

```
    var s = document.createElement('link');
    s.setAttribute('href', 'file:///home/simha/.public_html/new1.css');
    s.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    alert('Stylesheet injected!');
```

the content of the file:///home/simha/.public_html/new1.css

`body { background-color: #0000ee !important; }`

I run the code in the firebug console and the following appears in the head of the html

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="file:///home/simha/.public_html/new1.css">
```

But there no change in the background color (change to blue) of the body.

I checked the css rule independently from editing the css in firebug, the background color changes to blue.

I have apache web server installed. So i also tried instead of "file:///home/simha/.public_html/new1.css" to "localhost/~simha/new1.css" still it does not work.

I am using firefox browser.

Comment: And does the body have an actual size, did you try using `html` instead. Did you open the console to check that the file was actually loaded, and did not return a 404 or other error.

Comment: And download a [server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Comment: when i added the css code directly to the html background turns blue. As i mentioned i am trying this on any website. I tried on stackoverflow. There is no problem with the css rule. I checked it with firebug.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi give a look at my answer.

Comment: "file:///" is the problem since it makes no sense in a client environment

Comment: check this http://thudjs.tumblr.com/post/637855087/stylesheet-onload-or-lack-thereof

Comment: Please see the edited question. I tried with the localhost also.

Comment: Pavan Ram, i think my style sheet is not loading. the page you sent has a script. So i how to do it in my case

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi I just tried with busybox's httpd server, if I load it from an `http` URL on Firefox is fine. What do you see on the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

That's because for security reasons external resources can be loaded from a local URI scheme (like `file:`) only if the document has been loaded from a local URI too.

Comment: I think the problem is with the file: or localhost. because i saved the file in the dropbox and gave that address it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 s.setAttribute('href', 'new1.css');
```

Comment: but how will it know the path of new1.css

Comment: 'new1.css' will be relative to the folder of the file in which you are requesting it. If you are in /mywebsite, it will check for /mywebsite/new1.css. As it's been already said, you can't use an absolute file path like "file:///home/username/...", it would be a security issue to give access to the file system. Instead, try using a relative path like that. Otherwise, use the / character to specify a path relative to the root of your website (and not of your filesystem).

Comment: thankyou. It make sense, but it should atleast allow for sake of testing in the firebug

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet named `new1.css` needs to be referenced in relation to the server's document root.

So you're using Apache, which means you setup the apache2.conf (or httpd.conf, etc) as well as the site conf file(s).  The path you used in this config for `DocumentRoot` will be the reference point.  From there you simply put `/path/to/new1.css`.

So in your case,

```
file:///home/simha/.public_html/new1.css
```

will translate to

```
/new1.css
```

So your final code will be

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/new1.css">
```

When you put `file:///` prefixing an address, it's not using the server **filesystem** to load the file, it's using the client/user.  This is due to the blank string where the hostname should be - `file://_BLANKHOSTNAME_/`.  ***[Here's more info if you're curious.](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/quality/networking/testing/filetests.html)***

For your `localhost/new1.css` to work, it needs to be prefixed with `http://` like this:

```
href="http://localhost/new1.css"
```

Otherwise it's interpreting `localhost` as if it were a **directory name** and not the hostname.

Comment: but cant we refer from public_html folder which we give access for local user. Should the file be called only from the document root.

Comment: I was writing it with http:// but stackover flow says localhost is not allowd and it should be in block code, which i dont know how to make. so i removed the http:

Comment: The web server is not launched under the user's name, nor does it have the same credentials.  However, if you are using a shared hosting setup, the document root is going to adjust for each user based on whatever settings you give them.  Either way, using `href="new1.css"` without the preceding `/` will work as long as that CSS file is in the same directory as the HTML file requesting it (and permissions are allowing the webserver to read both files).  Make sure the CSS file has full permissions (`chmod 777 new1.css`) to rule that out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with file: or localhost in firefox, I saved the file in dropbox and used that link it worked.

```
    var s = document.createElement('link');
    s.setAttribute('href', 'https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/new1.css?w=AACLoomOT900PfGVqEuu9rHP4NlewdOq0KaSZbhzmgyG1A&dl=1');
    s.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    alert('Stylesheet injected!');
```

But is there any setting in the linux for apache and file to make it work locally.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem might be the path you have

```
file:///home/simha/.public_html/new1.css
```

When you allow per user directories in Apache, it is usually `public_html` *without* a leading dot. So, when you rename the directory to `/home/simha/public_html`, `http://localhost/~simha/new1.css` should work as expected.

Your code works as is, at least when you use an absolute URL

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
```

In the Javascript, I replaced your CSS with the publicly accessible Bootstrap CSS

```js
s.setAttribute('href', 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

everything else is left as is, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qv8uv/)

As you can see, the button is coloured like the Info button in the docs at [Bootstrap - Buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons).

Answer (score 0):

If you did not solve this problem yet,

1. Serve all static content from a (http) server of your choice. Do not use file system paths. Firefox wont load them ( in a web page context )
2. Try to put all the static resources along with your
   html, and serve them with relative url.

Now try this thing. open view source, and check if the css path is clickable and is fetching the content according to your expectation. If not, directly access that file from address bar of the browser. (Make sure your localhost is running and you have put all your files related to this in the web server - I normally use /var/www/). Use the path that works like this in your html too. (no file:// protocol, remember).

If you are not success by these, WWJD.

Also tell us when you are successful.